# Windows phone Grid - how hide row and column?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, grid

I create application with MVVM Cross. I use this grid:

```
 <Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Row ="0" Grid.Column ="0" />
    <Image Grid.Row ="0" Grid.Column ="1" />
    <Image Grid.Row ="1" Grid.Column ="0" />
    <Image Grid.Row ="1" Grid.Column ="1" />  
 </Grid>
```

[image]

When I click on the picture it should fill the entire grid. The new press displays all pictures.
I click image1 - image1 fill the entire grid. Other images are hidden. I can hide other images but the selected  image is not stretched.
 How to implement it? Perhaps you need to use a different type of panels?

Comment: You can use Grid.RowSpan and Grid.ColumnSpan when the click event is fired and stretch the image to fill, I guess.

Comment: I use Mvvm Cross. I think it will not be easy.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know about MvvmCross. It works otherwise writing the following in the click event, Grid.SetColumnSpan(image1, 2);
Grid.SetRowSpan(image1, 2);

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you would like to attain but to arrange images like on drawing you have to use this code:

```
 <Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid Grid.Row = "0" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column ="0" />
    <Image Grid.Column ="1" />
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row = "1" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column ="0" />
    <Image Grid.Column ="1" />
</Grid>

 </Grid>
```